# MS Word: Any way to temporarily keep line numbers from updating?

Tags: microsoft-word

I printed a revision of a manuscript in MS Word, and did some remarks what I want to change on the paper. There are line numbers, so it's easy to locate the place in 30+ pages long document. Now I am back at my computer and I want to edit those changes in.

The problem is that as I edit the document, the line numbers change and no longer correspond to those in the printed document :-)

The obvious solution would be to process the changes backwards, from the highest line numbers to the lowest. But I need to follow the logical line in the paper in the proper direction.

So: **is there any way to turn off temporarily the updating of the line numbers, so they just stay where they are?**

Comment: After each change, you could toggle back the "Original" tracking view (in Word 2010 - it may be renamed something else in later versions) so you see the original text only and the "old" line numbers.  Then once you go to spot of next edit, change the tracking view back to your usual view showing track changes (eg Final: Show Markup)

Comment: @Tanya aaah! Oh yeah, I forgot I could use this! I am using revisions anyway so it's no problem! Thanks!! :-)